# Allow users of an npm package to override a package file with a local file

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, ecmascript-6

I am building an npm package for React Native. I would like to have a file, `Class.js` in my package that user would load in a normal way, like `import {Class} from 'package'`.

I would like however, to allow the user to create their own file at a specific location in their React Native project, say at `/App/Class.js`, and have this file override the default class from the package. So when the user uses `import {Class} from 'package'`, it will load Class from the file at `/App/Class.js` if present, otherwise it would load it from the `Class.js` file in the package. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what builder/bundler are you using? Usually this feature is named **aliasing**. For example if you are using **babel** in your pipeline, you can try **babel-plugin-module-resolver**. In other cases there should be other tools

Comment: @dm.shpak React Native uses babel. I am looking into that package and it looks like it could be useful, but I would need the alias to point to different locations, based on whether not the Class.js file exists in the user's project. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: It may be possible. The bundler is looking for source in different places and usually select the first found item. By default React native using Metro bundler. It going throw your sources and using different tools (babel, typescript, etc). Take a look there [https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration#resolverequest].

Comment: Thanks, I ended up figuring something out with babel-plugin-module-resolver, where I just had an alias with multiple path options, and it looks like it just goes through them until it finds one that works